# Convert long value to HANDLE

Tags: c++, windows

I am using DuplicateHandle to duplicate a handle and then I pass that handle via IPC to the child process. The child process gets the handle value as string say "388". I convert that to long and assign it to a HANDLE. Is this correct:

```
WCHAR* pszEnd = NULL; 
myToken = (HANDLE) wcstol(tokenHandleString, &pszEnd, 10);
```

Comment: I'm sorry - is your question whether or not the above code will work?  Have you tried running it to find out?

Comment: Why are you passing it as a string?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the ideal solution would be to pass it as binary instead of a string. However the above method does work.